# using hibernate envers with unique table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am starting a Java project with Hibernate and found interesting the way the Envers work, but I wonder if you can only have a table to store all changes to the system? I do not know if I'm asking something impossible.

What I need are columns: user, action (insert / update ...), table name and field changed.

I do not know if this can be done with Envers or if there is another way.

Comment: Not sure if it is feasible in envers but in the past I did tried to do store auditing info as the way you said, and it turned out to be a nightmare

Answer (score 0):

What you described isn't possible with Envers; however, you can write your own Hibernate Listener implementations to accomplish such a task easily and integrate that directly.